# How to discover which TLSv1.2 cihpering method is used by Savon in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tls1.2, savon

In my RubyOnRails application I'm connecting to an external WebService (provided by the customer) through the excellent [Savon gem](http://savonrb.com/).

The provider is asking to me which cihpering method method I'm using because he doesn't want the `AES256-SHA256` because is considered insecure.

How can I know which one I'm using? In my Savon client instance I'm not setting anything, here is an example

> @client = Savon.client(
>             wsdl: *the wsdl*,
>             logger: Rails.logger,
>             log_level: :info,
>             log: true
>           )

Does Savon gets it from the server? Or does it have one set by default?

Comment: The server and your browser agree on which TLS version & ciphers to use when the initial connection is made. Their server will have a list of acceptable versions & ciphers and subsequently your browser will have a list that it is able to use. I would suggest that you have a look at how to view this information for your specific browser version.